# Issues in R Java Integration

Tags: java, r, rjava

I have main java program that will run a function from another class. I have script in R which connected with the function class in my Java project. I will give a simple example from my code.

`App.java`

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String input = "Hello world.";
    ResultSequence sequence = new ResultSequence();
    sequence.runResultSeq(input);
}
```

`ResultSequence.java`

```java
public class ResultSequence {
    String x;
    private Rengine r;

    public void runResultSeq(String x) { 
       Rengine re = new Rengine(new String[]{"--no-save"}, false, null);
       System.out.println(re.eval("x =" + x));
       File rScript = new File("src/application/rscript/check.R");
       System.out.println(rScript);
       System.out.println(re.eval("source(\""+rScript.toURI().getPath().substring(1)+"\")"));
       System.out.println(re.eval("abc <- abc(x)"));
       System.out.println(r.eval("abc"));
       re.end();
    }
}
```

check.R

```r
abc <- function(x) {
  library(stringi)
  library(stringr)
  y = substring(x,4)
  y
}
```

I run my main code in Java, but there is an error as if the code doesn't read the R script. I use rJava, and I am beginner in R Java Integration. Please help my problem, because I don't know which one from the part my code should be fixed. I'm sorry for my stupid question, but I've searched on many sources and practices it, it doesn't change my error result. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: Could you be more specific in the kind of error occurs